# NextJS v13.4+ Layout Structure

Tags: next.js13, sanity

Can anyone help me? I have a situation where I have NextJS V13.4+ & Sanity CMS. I tried to do (user) and (admin) folders. Admin for sanity cms.
Now I have a problem layout structure.  Can I use "not-found.js" in (user) folder because if not I need to implement it to "Root" layout and there is not Nav and Footer and if it these will come in sanity screen like this (down):
And if I do not have RootLayout outside the (user) folder then I can't use "not-found.js"

[Sanity View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Plw0z.png)
[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdFXP.png)

I try to find way where sanity doesn't have nothing but the sanity things (not nav or footer) but in (user) folder we have nav & footer ofc and "not-found.js" we see these too.

https://github.com/donhamalainen/boggostudio_v2

Comment: Here you is Github
https://github.com/donhamalainen/boggostudio_v2